# RedCloth dynamic tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, controller, redcloth

I'm trying to make a custom tag for RedCloth. However, I need to fetch some data from the database and base the tag on that. I.e. when writing "image. 1" it should fetch a user uploaded picture from the database with id #1.

But I can't figure out how to pass current_user (or other crucial instance variables from the controller) to the module. I imagine that the code could look something like this:

```
module RedclothExtension
  def image(opts)
    @image = User.find(current_user.id).images.where(id: opts[:text])
    "#{@image.title}"    
  end 
end
```

As I see it there are two ways:

1. Passing the needed variables to the module.
2. Fetching the instance variables from the controller.

But how do i do this exactly? Or is there a smarter way?